# How to create toggler in Bootstrap v5.1?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to implement a Navbar toggler referring the [Bootstrap v5.1 documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#toggler). I want to display the brand name on the left and the toggler on the right. Though this code is displaying the same but when I click the toggler the drop down menu is not showing and I am unable to figure out where the problem lies. How can I fix this?

Here's the code:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Here's the image of the working of the code

[image: Here's the image of the working of the code]

Comment: The code works fine: https://codeply.com/p/O9y81CuZu6 .. please make sure you're properly referencing Bootstrap 5 javascript

Comment: You haven't loaded the JavaScript file for Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code is perfect. But you forget to connect JavaScript in your code.That's why the Navbar toggler isn't working perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That worked! If I am not wrong is this because bootstrap library uses some javascript?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Because it contains CSS- and JavaScript-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation, and other interface components.That's why you need to connect the js also.